# Python/Anaconda Package Mess

Tags: python, anaconda, package, spleeter

I'm not exactly the most savvy when it comes to this kinda stuff. It also doesn't help that I'm normally a windows user but stuck on a mac for the time being. I'll cut to the chase in hopes of you guys maybe understanding what I'm trying to get at.

To make a long story short I was having issues getting spleeter working and found a video on youtube explaining how to create some kind of custom python installation environment or something and it didn't end up working for me but now I'm back at it trying to try things from scratch but whenever I finish uninstalling/reinstalling spleeter, python and anaconda and go to finally use the command line but it brings up an command line from when I was previously trying to get it to work with the custom python installation, giving a "file not found" errors and such. Now it seems like every time I go to try the command, it adds that on to the rest of the junk.

It's like I have to find a way to redefine what "!spleeter" does despite uninstalling it already. Or am I not actually uninstalling python properly? The (base) tag goes away when I launch terminal after removing the text from the bash profile and I sudo rm -rf'd my which python directory but it still shows up when I put in which python.

Any idea how I can undo this mess I made for myself?

bonus points if you can teach me an easy-to-understand way how to build myspleeter or how to launch the application without it crashing immediately

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately my inability to understand my own problem is part of the problem itself as I explained it as succinctly as I could.